# Access Point - should I be able to connect to it even when it's not connected to a network

Tags: networking, netgear, access-point

Should I be able to connect to my wireless access point (AP) even when the AP is not connected to the network.

I'm just trying to work out why I can't connect to the AP and wanted to know if I had to connect to a network to test the connection to the AP.

Answer (score 2):

If the access point is powered on and configured to operate, then you can almost certainly connect at the Data link layer, but without an external connection, it may not provide services like DHCP and DNS that almost every computer depends on to actually do anything useful.

If the AP doesn't provide DHCP, then you could possibly connect by providing static IP addressing.  If it doesn't have any form of name-resolution, then you would probably have to connect by IP addresses, or by using some kind of pear-to-pear name resolution.

Comment: Is that anything like apple-to-apple name resolution?  What if I'm on Windows?

Comment: @Ladadadada, Yeah I was thinking of something like this.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_Name_Resolution_Protocol and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDNS

Answer (score 0):

It depends.  On some access points, yes.  On some access points, no.